# No of rectangles formed from N square

Tags: c, math

I am solving this question on how many rectangles can be formed from N square of unit length. I came across this formula ⌊3n/2⌋−1 for (n>1) this is wrong formula.
Can anyone explain this formula and the given code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
int i,j,n,cnt=0;
scanf("%d",&n);
int k= sqrt(n);
for(i=1;i<=k;i++)
    for(j=i+1;i*j<=n;j++)
        cnt++;
cnt+=k;
printf("%d",cnt);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not "explain what I am doing" site. If you have a _specific_ problem, please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to find every possible integer length of the rectangle, and every possible width for each height, such that the total number of squares in the rectangle is bounded by N. (*)

The number `k = sqrt(N)` is to get rid of redundant checks: if width > k then maximum height < k and vice versa, meaning that by symmetry one only has to check for widths <= k, as this is equivalent to checking height <= k instead. Notice the integer casting rounds down.

The outer loop just counts every possible width, as mentioned above.
The inner loop counts every possible height such that width * height <= N. The index `i + 1` is to avoid counting the 1x1 square each time (assuming its not taken as a rectangle).

When combined these loops count every possible rectangle satisfying the condition (*).

See this post for why your formula doesn't work: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881386/number-of-possible-rectangles-from-at-most-n-identical-squares